# How To Make a button open a video file

Tags: winforms

I made a form that have few bottuns and I want
that every button will open a diffrent video in windows media player...
on a new window.

can't find the right code.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In each of your Button click event handlers you need to put:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\MyVideoFolder\MyVideo1.mp4");
```

This will open the named file in whatever default application is configured to open it. For instance, a HTML file would open in IE/Firefox/Chrome.

If you do not have Windows Media Player configured as the default for the video type you're trying to open then you can use a ProcessStartInfo instance to tell Process what application to use and include command line options.

[Link to Process documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Link to ProcessStartInfo documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Non-invocable member 'process' can't be used like a method